# Getting The ID Of URL

Tags: php

Let say we have set of URLs like this

```
yoursite.com/39827-key1-key2-key3
yoursite.com/132-key1-key2-key3
yoursite.com/9223455-key1-key2-key3
```

and so on
and let say with the help of .htaccess we can point all this urls to file say info.php
with the code

```
<?=id?>
```

it should gives the following ids (with respect to each url)

```
39827-key1-key2-key3
132-key1-key2-key3
9223455-key1-key2-key3
```

My question now is there any way that we only get the number before first (-)
let say

```
$id = 39827-key1-key2-key3
```

we need to make it

```
$realid = 39827
```

so i wonder if there any preg_replace or any any idea that can remove first (-) and all after it.

example

```
For $id = 39827-key1-key2-key3
$realid = (something),$id
Then finally $realid = 39827
```

it will helps me to create easy understandable url and retrieve its data from database.

Thanks you and sorry for poor english.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The quickest way (I think) would be with [`strpos`](http://php.net/strpos) and [`substr`](http://php.net/substr):

```
<?php
$str = "9223455-key1-key2-key3";     
$str = substr($str, 0, strpos($str, '-')); // 9223455
```

See [benchmarks against `explode` and `preg_match`](http://pastebin.com/h8X0bu6N) (1,000,000 iterations):

```
explode + array_shift: 2.7870438098907s
substr + strpos:       1.0809638500214s
preg_match:            1.8446760177612s
```

Comment: Thanks for posting the benchmarks. I typically dive for the array solutions because I can't ever remember the order of args to `substr() strpos()` and their ilk without going out to the docs.

Answer (score 1):

Use `explode()` with `array_shift()`:

```
$id = "39827-key1-key2-key3";
$realid = array_shift(explode("-", $id));
```

Comment: `explode("-", $id, 2)` would optimise this further.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly the quickest option would be to use `explode()`:

```
$id = '39827-key1-key2-key3';
$id_exp = explode('-', $id);
$num_id = $id_exp[0];
// You can get key1, key2, key3 via $id_exp[1], [2], [3], etc.
```

Another would be to use regex, but if you know the format is always this, there's not much point having the overhead of initialising the regex engine..